# Openlayers & NPM: can't load local .json file

Tags: json, npm, openlayers

I try to load a .json file in Openlayers from a local URI. As recommended, I'm using npm. However, the file doesn't seem to load. The file `example.json` is stored in the directory `data`, which is a subdirectory of where the main.js is located. The json file I'm using is valid according to jsonLINT.

```
var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource({
    url: 'data/example.json',
    format: new GeoJSON()
  }),
  style: function(feature) {
    style.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
    return style;
  }
});

var map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [ vectorLayer],
// ...
});
```

Messages in the console:

```
XHR GEThttp://localhost:1234/data/example.json [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 4ms]
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
XHR GEThttp://localhost:1234/data/example.json [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 14ms]
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I guess, the file doesn't load at all. If I change the adress to some file that isn't in the directory, I'll get the same messages.  On reload, I'd get the 304 error code twice. If I type in 'localhost:1234/data/example.json' as URL, it'll retrieve my main page (as with localhost:1234), not the json file I'd expect to see.

I'm a beginner with npm so I assume the problem is how files are handled with npm.

Comment: you say the `data` folder is within the folder containing the javascripts (which is a questionable layout by the way). Add it to the URL, like `js/data/example.json`

Comment: The json file must be in your server directory  (where localhost points to). This is likely the ./www. Just copy your data directory there.

Comment: Node.js serve your code at localhost:1234. so just check http://localhost:1234/data/example.json, can you see it? You should run `npm run build` instead and put data folder in `dist` folder.